# IAR workbench vector table ARM CortexM4

Tags: arm, iar, cortex-m

I am developping a firmware on an ARM CORTEX M4 processor, with IAR IDE (v7.71).

When a project is created in IAR workbench the start up code and vector table are in assembly files. But I want to change vector table from .S file to .C file.

In existing project, vector table in .s file is as below:

```
        SECTION CSTACK:DATA:NOROOT(3)

        SECTION .intvec:CODE:NOROOT(2)

        EXTERN  __iar_program_start
        PUBLIC  __vector_table

        DATA

__iar_init$$done:               ; The vector table is not needed
                                ; until after copy initialization is done

__vector_table
        DCD     sfe(CSTACK)
        DCD     __iar_program_start

        DCD     NMI_Handler
        DCD     HardFault_Handler
        DCD     MemManage_Handler
        DCD     BusFault_Handler
        DCD     UsageFault_Handler
        DCD     0
        DCD     0
        DCD     0
        DCD     0
        DCD     SVC_Handler
        DCD     DebugMon_Handler
        DCD     0
        DCD     PendSV_Handler
        DCD     SysTick_Handler
        ; External Interrupts        
        DCD     user_interrupt_Handler
```

this fiel is replaced by cfile with vector table as below :

```
typedef void (* exc_ptr_t)(void);

#pragma section = "CSTACK"

#pragma location = ".intvec"
__root exc_ptr_t user_vect_table[25] = 
{
    (exc_ptr_t)__sfe("CSTACK"),
    __iar_program_start,    
    NMI_Handler,
    HardFault_Handler,
    MemManage_Handler,
    BusFault_Handler,
    UsageFault_Handler,
    (exc_ptr_t)0xFFFFFFFF,
    (exc_ptr_t)0xFFFFFFFF,
    (exc_ptr_t)0xFFFFFFFF,
    (exc_ptr_t)0xFFFFFFFF,
    SVC_Handler,
    DebugMon_Handler,
    (exc_ptr_t)0xFFFFFFFF,
    PendSV_Handler,
    SysTick_Handler,

    user_interrupt_Handler
};
```

In c file , following statement is giving compilation error that the expression must be constant value.

> (exc_ptr_t)__sfe("CSTACK")

How to assign the CSTACK in vector table? What is correct way for doing so?
In .icf file, CSTACK block is declared with alignment 8 and size 0x1000.

Comment: Looking at my own startup file (for v5.50), major differences are that I have `#pragma language=extended` on top of the file, and array element is actually union of function pointer and void pointer: `union { void (*fun)(void); void * ptr; }` and CSTACK is assigned to void pointer: `{ .ptr = __sfe("CSTACK") },`. I'm not sure if that makes any difference (it shouldn't really).

Comment: Who is the vendor for your Cortex-M4?

Comment: one would have to wonder why you want to try to implement a vector table in C and make sure it is built right and links to the right place when this is so trivial in assembly.

Comment: where is CSTACK coming from?  the linker script?  Wouldnt you just set it to be the top of the memory for this device?  0x20001000 or whatever amount of ram you have?

Comment: with gnu tools you can just pull in variables created in the linker script, can you not do this in IAR?